# How to handle exceptions for generic return T

Tags: c#, .net, generics, exception, default

How can I return a new empty type of T if an exception occurs with-in the function body?

What would be the best way to x to a new T() in case there is a problem while Deserializing the xml?

Check out how I've got the catch block, and how would I handle this?

```
        public static T DeserializeXml<T>(this string xml) where T : class
    {

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        StreamReader sr = null;
        T x = null;
        //
        try
        {
            doc.LoadXml(xml); doc.Save(ms);
            ms.Position = 0;
            sr = new StreamReader(ms);
            XmlSerializer i = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            x = (T)i.Deserialize(sr);
        }
        catch (Exception) {
            x = null;
        }
        finally {
        sr.Close(); sr.Dispose(); ms.Close(); ms.Dispose();
        }
        //
        return x as T;
    }
```

Comment: So you want to swallow the exception and leave people wondering why they're getting a `null` back from the `DeserializeXml` function? Seems strange to me...

Comment: Why are you doing an `as` cast at the end when clearly x is of type T?

Comment: Lol, i did not want to return null, I wanted to return a new empty object of T

Comment: @StorefrontDoors doing an `as` cast operator does not make a null return an instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either return `default(T)`, or add a constraint to the generic type `where T : new()`, in which case you could return `new T()`.

Basically, `default(T)` is for cases where you don't know if `T` is a value or reference type.  It returns different things for different types -- null for classes, zero for numeric types, and empty instances of structs.  There's a good article [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

you can use [default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

```
return default(T);
```

Comment: Tilak, Like this,  catch (Exception)
            {
                x = default(T);
            }
            finally
            {
                s.Close(); s.Dispose(); m.Close(); m.Dispose();
            }
            return x;

Answer (score 3):

You can constrain `T` to have an empty constructor. Is that what you're asking?

```
public static T DeserializeXml<T>(this string xml) where T : class, new()
{
    //...
    catch
    {
        x = new T();
    }
    //...
    return x as T;       
}
```

Comment: Lukiffer, I need set x as a new empty / blank object of T, and return that empty object of T if something happens in the deserialization.

Comment: +1 - exact answer. @StorefrontDoors, if you need something else than `new T()` or `null` please describe what "empty/blank" means in your terms.

Answer (score 2):

All you should really need to do is

```
catch (Exception) {
    x = default(T);
}
```

or something similar.  Really, you can just `return` `null` in the `catch` clause; the `finally` clause is still guaranteed to run, unless you pull the power plug, and the `where T: class` constraint assures that default(T) will always be null.

Consider using some `using` blocks, instead of those closes and disposes.  Then you won't need a `finally` block at all.

```
public static T DeserializeXml<T>(this string xml) where T : class
{

    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T))
        {
            T x = null;

            try
            {
                doc.LoadXml(xml); doc.Save(ms);
                ms.Position = 0;
                sr = new StreamReader(ms);
                XmlSerializer i = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                x = (T)i.Deserialize(sr);
            }
            catch (Exception) {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
    return x;
}
```

Comment: +1 especially for `using` suggestion. I suspect that OP does not want `default(T)` which will always return `null` with current `:class` restriction.